# In Batch, using FIND or FINDSTR and saving its output to a variable with SET

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a file that contains a lot of lines, e.g.

```
foo=1
foobar=2
bar=3
```

I want to use `FIND` (or `FINDSTR`) to read this file and use `SET` to set a variable `foobar` to `2`, etc.

I would much prefer to only use Batch and tools that come with Windows - no third-party tools. But if it's impossible without any, then I'm open to using them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you need `find` or `findstr` for?

If your file is structured as you suggest, then

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (filename) do set "%%a"
```

will set those variables to the values.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I forgot that `for` was a thing :|. However, I get an error with this: "%%a was unexpected at this time"?

Comment: Ahh nevermind, I did a little research and found that you only need one `%` if you're doing `FOR` directly through the commandline, rather than in a Batch script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the file holding your "var=value" lines is set.txt, the following will do it:

```
for /f "delims=^= tokens=1-2" %%v in (set.txt) do set %%v=%%w
```

I've made assumptions -- if there are more requirements/restrictions than how I've addressed the problem you must clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned tools that come with Windows as an option:

**PowerShell** offers a simple and flexible solution (`file` is assumed as the name of the input file):

```powershell
$settings = ConvertFrom-StringData (Get-Content -Raw file)
```

The command above (executed interactively or from a `*.ps1` file) reads all `=`-separated key-value pairs into a single *hash table*, so you can easily access individual settings on demand; e.g.:

```powershell
$settings.foobar  # -> 2
```